# Why change value in new hash affect the old hash

Tags: ruby

Assume we have

```
hash = { a: 1, b: 2 }
hash2 = hash.to_hash
```

when I change value in hash2 it affect value in hash

```
hash2[:a] = 5
# hash[:a] = 5
```

Why ruby acts like that ?
How to fix this ?

Comment: For one, you could write `hash2 = {}.merge(hash)`.

Comment: or just `hash.merge`

Comment: or even `hash.dup`

Comment: ov even hash.clone

Comment: @Taoufik see [on dup vs clone](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Object.html#method-i-dup-label-on+dup+vs+clone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Calling `to_hash` on a Hash returns itself](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Hash.html#method-i-to_hash). `hash` and `hash2` are the same object.

```
2.6.5 :001 > hash = { a: 1, b: 2 }
 => {:a=>1, :b=>2} 
2.6.5 :002 > hash2 = hash.to_hash
 => {:a=>1, :b=>2} 
2.6.5 :003 > hash.object_id
 => 70244375263800 
2.6.5 :004 > hash2.object_id
 => 70244375263800
```